# Change active and inactive windows border colors in Win8

Tags: windows-8

I am running multiple windows on the Desktop (non-Metro) side of Win8. The active window has a gray border (good) but all of the inactive windows have white borders (bad). This makes it impossible to see the windows clearly, since they all blend into the underlying white space on the other windows.

Is there any way to ask Win8 to use one border color for active windows and another non-white border color for inactive windows? I could not find this level of flexibility in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the border color is automatically chosen based on the prevailing color of your wallpaper.
You may change it by right-clicking an empty area of the Desktop and choosing **Personalize | Color**.
You may then choose alternative colors from the Color and Appearance window.

Selecting a high-contrast theme from the Personalization window will enable more options in the Color and Appearance window, including the ability to individually set the color of active and inactive windows.